# Using sqlalchemy, how to query if an entry has a column with a specific Numeric type value?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using python and sqlalchemy.

I have a db with a column that is Numeric type.

I want to query the db to check if there is an entry that has a specific value in the column.

Let's assume the value I want to look for is `1.04521`, and we know it's in the db.

I've tried

```
(result,) = session.query( exists().where(MyEntryClass.someNumericValue == 1.0452)
```

but `result` is still `False` even when I know it's in the db.

How do I check to see if there is an entry with a column with a specific Numeric value?

Post Original Question:
After a little more exploration, I think it's due to rounding/representation of the non-integer number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not getting the result because there are query executors like `all(), first(), scalar()` so use scalar:

```
result = session.query(exists().where(MyEntryClass.someNumericValue==1.0452)).scalar()
```

Comment: That didn't seem to solve the problem.  If I  do `queryRes = session.query(MyEntryClass)` then I get a Query object.  If I loop over each item in the query and print `MyEntryClass.someNumericValue`, it prints `Decimal('14.2748731614')` instead of just the value.  Also, if while I loop I try `MyEntryClass.someNumericValue == 14.2748731614`, it's False.

Comment: It means the problem is your data not the query. Did you try `where(MyEntryClass.someNumericValue==Decimal(1.0452))`

Comment: I tried `exists().where(Particle.DET_foreThreshold == Decimal(1.0452))` and it gives error saying `Decimal is not defined`.  I'm not sure where `Decimal` is defined so I can import it.